# Appending images from News API

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I have successfully implemented an API using newsapi.org, which is working great. However, the information I have is only text, and want to add the image in for each headline.  Not sure how to do this as the headlines are obviously changing.

There is a urlToImage tag within the JSON file, which presumably is what I need to implement this. You will see from my code that I have made a start at implementing this, but to no avail.

Any help on getting this implemented would be much appreciated.

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=mtv-news&apiKey=XXXXXX",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      processData(data);
    }
  });

  function processData(data) {
    var articleItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.articles.length; i++) {

      var author = data.articles[i].author;
      var title = data.articles[i].title;
      var description = data.articles[i].description;
      var urlToImage = data.articles[i].urlToImage;
      var artUrl = data.articles[i].url;


      var $author = $('<div class="author">Author: ' + author + "</div >");
      var $title = $("<a href=" + artUrl + '><div class="title">' + title + "</div ></a>");
      var $description = $("<a href=" + artUrl + '><div class="description">' + description + "</div ></a>");
      var $urlToImage = $("<a href=" + artUrl + '><img class="urlToImage" src">')
      $("#entertainment_news").append($author, $title, $description, $urlToImage);
      $("#entertainment_news").append("<br />");

      console.log(artUrl);
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="entertainment">
        <h3>ENTERTAINMENT</h3>
        <p id="entertainment_news"></p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append()` only accepts one argument and you have 4 jQuery objects. Forgo wrapping the HTML in a jQuery objects and just have them as regular strings.

```
var $author = '<div class="author">Author: ' + author + '</div >';
var $title  = '<a href=' + artUrl + '><div class="title">' + title + '</div ></a>';
var $description = '<a href=' + artUrl + '><div class="description">' + description + '</div ></a>';
```

You're also missing the source path for your image's `src` attribute. Assuming it's `urlToImage`, you'd do this:

```
var $urlToImage = '<a href=' + artUrl + '><img class="urlToImage" src=' + urlToImage + '>;
```

Then in your first `append()` call do this:

```
$("#entertainment_news").append($author + $title + $description + $urlToImage);
```

Comment: Noted, thank you. However, the images for the headlines are still not coming through; which is what I'm hoping to achieve.

Comment: Which part of your JSON returns the image path?

Comment: @KaliMa I updated my answer pointing out that you need to fill in the `src` attribute for your image. See if that works.

Comment: I am making sense of what you are trying to say, however, it returns nothing for me. Nothing even the text that was previously displayed.

I don't know if this helps, but this is the format that JSON file takes:
`"author": "Sarah Aspler",
"title": "Plan A Royal Wedding And We’ll Reveal When You’ll Get Married",
"description": "Take a bow and say your vow.",
"urlToImage": "https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2017-11/28/14/tmp/buzzfeed-prod-fastlane-01/5758e26a9e732fa6de10132b0dc3d843-0.jpg?crop=622:325;0,90",`

Comment: Thanks. What's `artUrl` look like?

Comment: Think it is to be like this maybe:

`var $urlToImage  = <a href="${artUrl}"><img class="urlToImage" src="${urlToImage}">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160110/discussion-between-carl-edwards-and-kali-ma).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt the src be the urlToImage rather than it being the class as you currently have it?